# SQL Server 2005 log file is getting too large

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transaction-log

I have an initial DB which I have to import very often during development, this DB is not large but it seems like the transaction log file is getting bigger and bigger, so each time I have to delete the database recreate it...

Does any body know to reduce/delete/limit this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a [ShrinkFile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907511) but I would also suggest you take a look at your Recovery Model. In SSMS, right-click on your database and choose properties. On the left, select Options. Then, on the right, you'll see a property named Recovery Model. You might want to change this from Full (if that's what it's set at) to Simple. This will help prevent your transaction log from growing so large. But you won't get point in time transaction log restores if you do this. It's a trade-off.

Comment: but the existing file is allready 13 GB ?? and it doesnt seem to change! any way thanx for ur answer, ill delete it for now and recreate it, hope it will not get as big as befor using the simple log modus

Comment: @O.D - What is your recovery model set at?

Comment: Voll, which i changed now to simple.

Comment: 'Voll' as in German for 'Full' ?

Comment: BAD bad advice, he may need full recovery.

Comment: @HLGEM - Would you relax a little and re-read my answer to him? I told him this approach has trade-offs, one of which would be the inability to do point in time restores.

Answer (score 3):

[How to use the DBCC SHRINKFILE statement to shrink the transaction log file in SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907511)

After dealing with the existing log file, I'd suggest reviewing the recovery model setting because it's likely set to "Full" when you might want to use "Simple" instead.  See [MSDN documentation for more detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191253%28SQL.90%29.aspx).